# How to extend .net interface without modifying it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'll start by saying that I am not a professional developer but have a ton of code that is used by various companies, mainly written with .net c# and vb.

With that said, I've never felt the need to get into extending existing classes and interfaces, and I'm struggling a bit now that I do want to do this, here's an example:

1. I have added a COM reference to my project of another application (can't edit this).
2. This reference has an interface that I want to extend, for example, _CellObject, I want to add some methods to it. In the past I'd build my own class to handle this, which works, but I think the more appropriate way would be to extend it.
3. So I build another interface, inherit from _CellObject and add my new methods.
4. Then I build a class that implements that interface, and this is where I realize I'm doing something wrong, all the methods from original interface must be added, but I don't want to do that. It's like I'm missing a "partial" somewhere or maybe this isn't possible?

Can someone push me in the right direction here?

Comment: It is possible to extend a interface, but it is not what you are looking for. What you want is to extend a class from the COM and it is not possible since it is a COM and for sure it does not have a partial on the class.
The only thing you can do is encapsulate the COM class into your class.

Comment: A COM interface is a contract, describes what the *other application* implements.  Extending it in your own code therefore does not make any sense, you have to improve the other application first.  Which usually is not possible since you don't have the source code for it, presumably what "can't edit this" means.  So stop right now, it isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I've decided to just wrap it the way I've done before.

Answer (score 1):

It's true.  If you extend an interface by inheriting from it, then when you implement a class that inherits from your new interface you will need to implement all the methods from your interface and the one it inherits from.  In a sense, that's kinda the point of having a new interface inherit from an existing one.  Otherwise you could just make a new interface and not inherit from an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

COM objects don't support implementation inheritance or polymorphism, so there won't be any protected members for you to override.  I don't typically see developers try to extend COM objects.  If you need to add related functionality, you can wrap it ([composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)) or you can write extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your fourth point makes me assume you have some default-implementation of the existing interface that you want to re-use within the new one. As others already mentioned you can extend the existing interface by inheriting. However you also need to implement the "old" methods within a class implementing the new interface.

If you want to re-use the default-implementaion within your new class, you can just provide it to its constructor. So you have this code:

```
interface IBase 
{ 
    void DoSomething(); 
}
interface IDerived : IBase
{ 
    void SoSomethingMore(); 
}

class MyBase : IBase 
{ 
    public void DoSomething() { ... } 
}
class MyDerived : IDerived
{
    private readonly MyBase _m;
    public MyDerived(MyBase m) { this._m = m; }

    // now you only need to forward the call for the existing interface to the injected base-class
    public void DoSomething() => this._m.DoSomething();
    public void DoSomethingMore() => ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actaully two way to extend interface without modifying it. First create antoher interface that inherit from that interface. Imagine you have `Interface A` and you want to extend it.

```
   interface A
{
    void SomeMethodA();
}

 interface B :A
{
    void SomeMethodB();
}
```

Second you can directly implement that interface.

```
   class C : A
   {
    public void SomeMethodA()
     {
        //your actual implementation
     }
   }
```

Comment: If I understand you correct, that's what I tried to do, the problem with implementing interface A is that it must include 100+ other methods that I don't want to deal with.

Comment: An interface defines a contract. You have to carry out  that contract. If you don't want to implement some of the methods you can throw `NotImplementedException` for the methods that you implement.

Comment: That's true, but I do want to implement the original implementation of those methods.

Answer (score 0):

One option (excluding the issues you have with COM) is to create a new interface and class which include the functionality of the older versions. Now your new class can inherit from the original class, keeping it's functionality while extending it with a new interface.

```
public interface _CellObject 
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface _CellObject2 : _CellObject 
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}


public class CellObject : _CellObject 
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}


public class CellObject2 : CellObject, _CellObject2 
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are too many methods/properties that I'd have to implement.

Comment: Yes but I'm saying with this method you only need to implement the new methods.

Comment: The original interface requires all the other methods, so how do I not implement them?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you extend another Interface from your existing Interface, this is called Interface Segregation.

```
public interface IContract
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface IContractChanged:IContract
{
    void DoSomethingMore();
}
```

And now you can implement the new contract IContractChanged to meet your needs.

Comment: The issue is that I can't implement without including all the Icontract's original properties and methods.